# DB25 printers to pc

Tags: networking, serial

If computer has a single parallel port then how can I connect three paralel printers on this pc ? Print Server seems a solution but seems expensive.However these  printers might be far away.Is there any other way like some kind of switch for these printers?I have seen somthing for serial though..

Comment: Parallel port? I just checked, we have 2013. Many years back, when parallel ports where actually used, there where manual switches to connect more than one printer to a port (or reverse, more than one computer to a printer, different models!).  Nevertheless, product recommendations are off-topic on [SE] sites, please read the [FAQ].

Comment: Recover a couple old computers from surplus.  Install Linux.  Setup, network, printers, and samba.

Comment: You have tagged `networking`.  Do you need help to setup PPP on your parallel port to connect this computer to a print server ?

Comment: If a computer has a single parallel port, it's probably too old to be in use.

Comment: I just sent a bunch of Parallel Print Servers to be recycled; half dozen or so.

Answer (score 1):

Print servers are the way to go.  Where I live, the reduced electricity spend would repay the capex in year.

If you don't want to, you can get PCI parallel port cards to add extra parallel ports.

There is such a thing as "parallel extender" which allows you run very long parallel connections, but it would probably cost more than the print server(s)